# Functionality similar RoR's collection_check_boxes in Phoenix?

Tags: phoenix-framework

Is it possible to recreate RoR's `collection_check_boxes` functionality with  `inputs_for` in Phoenix?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same, but take a look at [phoenix_mtm](https://github.com/adam12/phoenix_mtm). It's a collection of functions that make it easier to work with many_to_many Ecto associations and render checkboxes for them.